# Is it safe to say that…

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference

I’ve heard people often say “it is safe to say that … {statement}” but would it be correct if I used the *label* verb or any other? (“Is it safe to **label** that as…”)

Comment: "Is it safe to X," as a general matter, asks whether X is safe in the literal sense - i.e. whether there is danger involved. "Is it safe to say X," however, is often idiomatically used just as a way of confirming  that X is true (the theory behind this being, I suppose, that it would be "dangerous" to say X if X *weren't* true, because then you'd be lying). So, if you ask whether it's safe to label something in a certain way, it'll probably sound like you're literally asking whether there is any danger in doing so.

Answer (score 1):

They're somewhat similar, but not the same for a few reasons.

First, the verb "label" can only have a *noun object*, while "It's safe to say that..." can be followed by *any statement clause*.

So, while these two sentence mean the same thing:

> It's safe to **label this as** a good party.
> It's safe to **say that this is** a good party.

There is no equivalent with "label" for this:

> It's safe to say that I hope we have lots more parties like this.

Also, "it's safe to say that..." is a very common and natural expression, while "it's safe to label this..." is not at all idiomatic, and sounds somewhat unnatural. The expression doesn't even appear in an [Ngram search](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=it%27s+safe+to+say%2Cit%27s+safe+to+label&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cit%20%27s%20safe%20to%20say%3B%2Cc0).

It's not common in English to use "label" in casual speech. In fact, "labelling" things has had an [increasingly negative association](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=label&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clabel%3B%2Cc0) for the last 20 years or so, so people are using it less and less.